# Resolving TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, database, file, csv

I'm trying to create a file that includes the names only on file 1 and that are not on file 1. I get an error running the following code:

```
import pandas
import csv
f = pandas.read_csv('hillelclass2019.csv')
g = pandas.read_csv('shabsignup.csv')
for i in range(193): #length of data1
    x = str(f['First Name'][i]) + " " + str(f['Last Name'][i]) #first name + last name
    a = 0 #initial
    for j in range(25): #length of data2
        if g['Name'][j] == x: #if name == name on other sheet, then a == 1
            a == 1
    if a == 0: #if names are not equal 
        with open('noshab.csv', 'a') as f: #write name to file
            wtr = csv.writer(f, delimiter= ',')
            wtr.writerow( [x,i])
```

the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/kz/351q8p011qjc2x4k9srypcqc0000gn/T/tmpf4VgQX.py in <module>()
      5 g = pandas.read_csv('shabsignup.csv')
      6 for i in range(193): #length of data1
----> 7     x = str(f['First Name'][i]) + " " + str(f['Last Name'][i]) #first name + last name
      8     a = 0 #initial
      9     for j in range(25): #length of data2

TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The code works when I set i in range(1) and only run 1 iteration, but does not work for multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have bound `f` to a file object in your loop so after one iteration  it no longer points to your `df` so `f['First Name'][i]` is `file_object['First Name'][i]` not `your_dataframe['First Name'][i]` so it obviously fails:

```
with open('noshab.csv', 'a') as f: # <- f is now a file object
```

Change the name from `f = pandas.read_csv('hillelclass2019.csv')` to `df = pandas.read_csv('hillelclass2019.csv')` and use `df` to refer to the dataframe in your code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('hillelclass2019.csv')
g = pandas.read_csv('shabsignup.csv')
for i in range(193): #length of data1
    x = str(df['First Name'][i]) + " " + str(df['Last Name'][i]) #first name + last name
```

On another note  `a == 1` inside the  `if g['Name'][j] == x:` is doing nothing, I presume you mean `a = 1`.

Comment: thank you! this is perfect. stupid error on my part. also error#2 at a == 1 instead of a=1 haha!

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you are trying to access the file instance like a dict.

`f['First Name']` or any other key access won't work on a file instance.

The error is referring to a `__getitem__` function, which is called under the hood anytime to try to use `[]` to index into an object, usually a dict or similarly keyed structure.

Comment: Ignore this answer, I see now your file instance is supposed to be a CSV file instance, which should offer a `__getitem__` interface. Just be aware that normal file instances don't offer this interface.